# how to detect the character encoding of a web page programmatically?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I want to get a web page source code by Qt or PyQt ,I know how to get the encoded source code ,then I need get the codec in order to convert it into plain text ,so the problem is how to detect the character encoding of a web page programmatically ?can anyone help ?

this page is encoded by UTF8 
http://www.flvxz.com/getFlv.php?url=aHR0cDojI3d3dy41Ni5jb20vdTk1L3ZfT1RFM05UYzBNakEuaHRtbA==

and this one is encoded by gb2312

http://www.qnwz.cn/html/yinlegushihui/magazine/2013/0524/425731.html

your answer should test on this 2 page

Comment: Detecting character encoding is always (at best) a heuristic, fragile activity. (In the most general case, it's impossible; what if an encoding was an encryption that /looked/ like another encoding, on purpose?) Aside from the pathological, many encodings are very similar. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QTextCodec::codecForHtml` static function.

> Tries to detect the encoding of the provided snippet of HTML in the
>   given byte array, ba, by checking the BOM (Byte Order Mark) and the
>   content-type meta header and returns a QTextCodec instance that is
>   capable of decoding the html to unicode. If the codec cannot be
>   detected from the content provided, defaultCodec is returned.

This will not work for pages with no encoding meta-tag. For example, the first link you've posted has no encoding tag (this is not HTML, so there can't be any tags), encoding is specified in HTTP header named 'Content-type'. You need to check its value. It can be retrieved using `QHttpHeader::contentType` if you use Qt to download the page.

Answer (score 0):

Finally ,I found by using PyQt’s QtextStream , QTextCodec and chardet ,we can get a web page code more securely
even for this bad page
http://www.qnwz.cn/html/yinlegushihui/magazine/2013/0524/425731.html

this script 
http://www.flvxz.com/getFlv.php?url=aHR0cDojI3d3dy41Ni5jb20vdTk1L3ZfT1RFM05UYzBNakEuaHRtbA==

and this page without chardet in its source code 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802962(v=office.12).aspx

code sees here
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.python/8_1oNMidxzE/zMztIlE3mAYJ